# Why field TO is empty after sending emails from list?

Tags: python, email, smtplib

I have the following code which makes a list from email.txt and then sends emails to each item. I use a list instead of a loop.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding= utf-8 -*-

SMTPserver = '' 

import sys
import os
import re

import email
from smtplib import SMTP      
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText

body="""\
hello
"""

with open("email.txt") as myfile:
    lines = myfile.readlines(500)
    to  = [line.strip() for line in lines] 

try:
    msg = MIMEText(body.encode('utf-8'), 'html', 'UTF-8')
    msg['Subject']=  'subject' 
    msg['From']   = email.utils.formataddr(('expert', 'mymail@site.com'))
    msg['Content-Type'] = "text/html; charset=utf-8"

    conn = SMTP(SMTPserver)
    conn.set_debuglevel(False)
    conn.login('info', 'password')
    try:
        conn.sendmail(msg.get('From'), to, msg.as_string())
    finally:
        conn.close()

except Exception, exc:
    sys.exit( "mail failed; %s" % str(exc) )
```

When the user receives the email he can't see the field TO because this field will be empty. I would like the recipient to see the TO field once in the email.
How should I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set message header value for `to` also as:

```
msg['to'] = "someone@somesite.com"
```

You may have to populate that value from the `to` list that you've read from the file. So you may have to iterate over all the values either one at a time or all of them together, structuring it how your mail provider supports it.

Something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding= utf-8 -*-

SMTPserver = '' 

import sys
import os
import re
import email
from smtplib import SMTP      
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText

body="""\

hello

"""

with open("email.txt") as myfile:
    lines = myfile.readlines(500)
    to  = [line.strip() for line in lines] 

for to_email in to:    
    try:
        msg = MIMEText(body.encode('utf-8'), 'html', 'UTF-8')
        msg['Subject'] = 'subject' 
        msg['From'] = email.utils.formataddr(('expert', 'mymail@site.com'))
        msg['Content-Type'] = "text/html; charset=utf-8"
        msg['to'] = to_email

        conn = SMTP(SMTPserver)
        conn.set_debuglevel(False)
        conn.login('info', 'password')
        conn.sendmail(msg.get('From'), to, msg.as_string())

    except Exception, exc:
        sys.exit( "mail failed; %s" % str(exc))
    finally:
        conn.close()
```

> There is no need to have nested `try` blocks.
>
> You may create the connection outside the loop and keep it open until all the mails are sent and close it afterwards.
>
> This is not a copy-paste code, I haven't tested it too. Please use it to implement a suitable solution.